# Make PDO connection available throughout the application while using autoloader PSR-4

Tags: php, pdo, psr-4

How to make PDO instance available throughout entire application in PHP ?

I'm using autoload from PS4 allowing to access any class in the application by using :

```
use Namespace\ClassName;
```

In the case the class has static method, I can use this very handful way to call the method :

```
Class::method();
```

I would like to be able to initiate a PDO connection once in the application and be able to use it everywhere.
I already have a PDO class with all the convenient methods to request the database. When this class is instanciated, it connects to the database and store the connection in a class attribute.

Some solutions are available but it has some drawbacks :

1) Instanciate the PDO once and pass it to the constructor of classes.
I'm not a big fan of this strategy because it forces me to instanciate classes using

```
$instance = new Class($pdo);
Class->method();
```

Which is less pretty than Class::method();

2) Make pdo instance Global

I don't know why but I saw everywhere it was a bad idea. Instinctively I'm not a fan of it too.

3) Pass it to methods while using them.

It looks very dirty to me and not convenient at all.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve it ?

Comment: The first option is the recommended one, but use whatever floats your goat. This is too opinion based question.

Comment: Sounds like you need dependency injection - or containers as in [PSR-11](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/).